# YUV 422 to PNG/JPG/

Tags: python, image, converters, yuv

After searching the internet for several days, i am searching for a method or program to transform pictures taken in the YUV 422 format to something useable. PNG/BMP or JPG would be fine.

does anybody has knowledge for such a tool/library/method? preferably a python library that can do the conversion of these files?

i came across ImageMagick, but it runs in my powershell, it doens't output an error, but no conversion is done.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Please share your image (Dropbox or Google Drive or similar) and the height and width in pixels.

Comment: You should be able to do that using Python Wand, which is based upon ImageMagick. ImageMagick can convert from YUV 4:2:2 to any other format that it supports such as PNG/BMP/JPG etc.

Comment: Hi, i tried using imagemagick in my command window, but w/o succes. however if i try to convert a JPG to PNG is seems to work. but if i want to go from YUV to something else it seems that it is busy for a few seconds and then terminates without telling the issue. i use this command ot do the conversion: magick convert -size 1750x520 -depth 8 -sampling-factor 4:2:2 85_TEST.YUV Foto_YUVConvert.png   i will see if i can upload the image somehwere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it using "ffmpeg" using this command :

```
    ffmpeg -s 1750x520 -pix_fmt uyvy422 -i 85_TEST.YUV -f image2 -pix_fmt rgb24 test_2.png
```

Works like a charm!